# Python3 counting UTF-16 code points in a string

Tags: python, unicode

I am trying to figure out how to either convert `UTF-16` offsets to `UTF-8` offsets, or somehow be able to count the # of `UTF-16` code points in a string. (I think in order to do the former, you have to do the latter anyways.)

Sanity check: I am correct that the `len()` function, when operated on a python string returns the number of code points in it in `UTF-8`?

I need to do this because [the LSP protocol](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specifications/specification-3-16/#textDocuments) requires the offsets to be in `UTF-16`, and I am trying to build something with LSP in mind.

I can't seem to find how to do this, the only [python LSP server](https://github.com/palantir/python-language-server/issues/770) I know of doesn't even handle this conversion itself.

Comment: There's no such thing as a UTF-16 code point. There are Unicode code points though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python has two datatypes which can be used for characters, neither of which natively represents UTF-16 code units.

In Python-3, strings are represented as `str` objects, which are conceptually vectors of unicode codepoints. So the length of a `str` is the number of Unicode characters it contains, and `len("")` is 1, just as with any other single character. That's independent of the fact that `""` requires two UTF-16 code units (or four UTF-8 code units).

Python-3 also has a `bytes` object, which is a vector of bytes (as its name suggests). You can encode a `str` into a sequence of bytes using the `encode` method, specifying some encoding. So if you want to produce the stream of bytes representing the character "" in UTF-16LE, you would invoke `"".encode('utf-16-le')`.

Specifying `le` (for little-endian) is important because `encode` produces a stream of bytes, not UTF-16 code units, and each code unit requires two bytes since it's a 16-bit number. If you don't specify a byte order, as in `encode('utf-16')`, you'll find a two-byte UFtF-16 Byte Order Mark at the beginning of the encoded stream.

Since the UTF-16 encoding requires exactly two bytes for each UTF-16 code unit, you can get the UTF-16 length of a unicode string by dividing the length of the encoded bytes object by two: `s.encode('utf-16-le')//2`.

But that's a pretty clunky way to convert between UTF-16 offsets and character indexes. Instead, you can just use the fact that characters representable with a single UTF-16 code unit are precisely the characters with codepoints less than 65536 (2<sup>16</sup>):

```
def utf16len(c):
    """Returns the length of the single character 'c'
       in UTF-16 code units."""
    return 1 if ord(c) < 65536 else 2
```

Answer (score 1):

For counting the bytes, including BOM, `len(str.encode("utf-16"))` would work. You can use `utf-16-le` for bytes without BOM.

Example:

```
>>> len("abcd".encode("utf-16"))
10
>>> len("abcd".encode("utf-16-le"))
8
```

As for your question: No, `len(str)`  in Python checks the number of decoded characters. If a character takes 4 UTF-8 code points, it still counts as 1.

Comment: Sorry can you please clarify, the example they used docs is `""`. And I quote "since  is represented using two code units in UTF-16".

But `len("".encode("UTF-16-le")) == 4`. So how come there is a discrepancy.

Comment: `UTF-16` comes in pairs of bytes. `""` is represented as 4 bytes, or 2 pairs. If you wish to count the pairs, you can just divide it by 2. The byte count is guaranteed to be even, no need check if it doesn't divide by 2.

Comment: @Dog By the way, I think the correct terminology is that you want the number of `UTF-16` code units. Each code unit is 2 bytes. 1 `UTF-16` Code point can be composed of 1 or 2 code units, which can in turn be composed of 2 or 4 bytes.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was very confused.